# How to cancel an event without using e.Cancel method?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I want to cancel the Data gridview cell click event

```
private void gridViewHistory_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{      
}
```

but this eventargs doesn't have cancel event, How to cancel that event ?
May be this question has a very easy answer but still i am stuck it in, needs help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

WinForms events are just multicast delegates then they can't be canceled (in the sense of *stop propagation of the event*) unless this situation is handled by the object that exposes the event (but I'm not aware of any object that supports this, usually events are notifications).

That said, some events has argument with a `Cancel` property, it's used by the object to *cancel the action* that should be performed because of that event. Again if the implementation does not provide that property there is not anything you can do to change this behavior.

In your case you should override the `OnCellClick` method of `DataGridView` to handle that in the way you prefer (if you do not call the base class then cell won't get the click event and `CellClick` event won't be fired).

Comment: Multicast delegates have nothing to do with the fact that this event can't be canceled.

Answer (score 1):

Not all events can be cancelled. You can choose to not do anything in your event handler but that doesn't mean you can cancel it.

So, unless there is a specific `Cancel` type method you **Cannot** cancel the event.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `CellValidating` event:

```
private void gridViewHistory_CellValidating(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (.....)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: but it gives the error - Operation did not succeed because the program cannot commit or quit a cell value change, when i assign data source to the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the

> return;

statement, but this only works for asp:LinkButton OnClick events that do not then pass over to other post events, such as an UpdateCommand.